# Footheight and footrule using titlesec and geometry

Tags: header-footer, titlesec, geometry

Consider the following MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside]{article}

\usepackage[width=14cm,left=3.5cm,marginparwidth=3cm,marginparsep=0.35cm,
height=21cm,top=3.7cm,headsep=1cm,headheight=1.6cm,footskip=1.7cm,showframe]{geometry}

\usepackage[pagestyles,outermarks]{titlesec}
\newpagestyle{foo}{%
  \headrule\sethead
  [\thepage][][{\includegraphics[height=1.5cm]{foo.jpg}}]
  {{\includegraphics[height=1.5cm]{foo.jpg}}}{}{\thepage}
  \footrule
  \setfoot
  {}{\includegraphics[height=1cm,width=\textwidth]{bar.jpg}}{}
  }
\pagestyle{foo}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-5]
\end{document}
```

The image in the footer overlaps with the `footrule` and therefore the latter is not shown as it can be seen in the following image:

[image]

How can I fix this?
More generally, is there a way to increase the `footheight` when using the geometry package? (I can increase the head height with the `headheight` option but the foot height seems to be fixed, as it can be seen in the next image).

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can lower the picture using `\raisebox`

```
\raisebox{-1cm}{\includegraphics[height=1cm,width=\textwidth]{bar.jpg}}
```

Code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside]{article}

\usepackage[width=14cm,left=3.5cm,marginparwidth=3cm,marginparsep=0.35cm,
height=21cm,top=3.7cm,headsep=1cm,headheight=1.6cm,footskip=2cm,showframe]{geometry}

\usepackage[pagestyles,outermarks]{titlesec}
\newpagestyle{foo}{%
  \headrule\sethead
  [\thepage][][{\includegraphics[height=1.5cm]{foo.jpg}}]
  {{\includegraphics[height=1.5cm]{foo.jpg}}}{}{\thepage}
  \footrule
  \setfoot
  {}{\raisebox{-1cm}{\includegraphics[height=1cm,width=\textwidth]{bar.jpg}}}{}
  }
\pagestyle{foo}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-5]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Instead of hard coding `1cm`, you may use `\height` like

```
\raisebox{-0.8\height}{\includegraphics[height=1cm,width=\textwidth]{bar.jpg}}
```

---

With `fancyhdr`, things look neat.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside]{article}

\usepackage[width=14cm,left=3.5cm,marginparwidth=3cm,marginparsep=0.35cm,
height=21cm,top=3.7cm,headsep=1cm,headheight=1.6cm,footskip=2cm,showframe]{geometry}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}{%
  \fancyhf{}
  \fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
  \fancyhead[RE,LO]{\includegraphics[height=1.5cm]{foo.jpg}}
  \fancyfoot[C]{\includegraphics[height=1cm,width=\textwidth]{bar.jpg}}
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-5]
\end{document}
```

[image]